KeyError error at /registration/register/ 'email'
I have a problem. When clicking on the link http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register / returns the KeyError error at /accounts/register/
'email'. I program in django in pycharm.
I want to point out that there is a specific 'email' error here!
this is code:
registration/urls.py:
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('/register', views.register, name='register'),
]

registration/views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegistrationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = RegistrationForm()
            return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})


def register():
    print("hello!")

urls.py(In the project itself):
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('news/', include('news.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

register.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Регистрация</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Регистрация</h1>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.email }}
        {{ form.password1 }}
        {{ form.password2 }}
        <button type="submit">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

forms.py:
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email address'
        self.fields['password1'].label = 'Password'
        self.fields['password2'].label = 'Confirm Password'


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2')

I've tried a lot of YouTube videos and documentation, but still

It looks like you have define class Meta outside the RegistrationForm classs.

Share the full traceback.

In forms.py You have defined the Meta class outside of indention of RegistrationForm, And The KeyError will raise when the init of RegistrationForm called. To fix this problem try to write the Meta class in body of RegistrationForm class.
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email address'
        self.fields['password1'].label = 'Password'
        self.fields['password2'].label = 'Confirm Password'


    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2')


Django’s built-in Form UserCreationForm [github.com] does not have a fields['email'] hence the KeyError exception.
When you inherited this Form, you didn’t add this field either so it simply DOES NOT EXIST.
fields['username'] does exist though. You might want to use that especially if your model.email field is your USERNAME_FIELD.
